# Configure binding to perform predefined search in Tmux

Tags: macros, tmux

I'm trying to find a way to jump to the previous prompt in iTerm using tmux. Can I set a binding to search a unique phrase within my prompt?

Answer (score 1):

So to expand on Yuriy's answer. Inside your terminal you can run the following commands:

```
tmux copy-mode ; tmux send -X search-backward 'Example'
```

That should put your current tmux pane into copy-mode and then initiate a search for 'Example'. Now instead of typing that every time we want to search we'll create a shell script(lets say `/tmp/search.sh`) and then a tmux binding to that script

Contents of `/tmp/search.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tmux copy-mode ; tmux send -X search-backward 'These'
```

make sure you make it executable with `chmod +x /tmp/search.sh`. At this point you can test that it works by simply calling the script from your tmux session. To add it as a binding you can something akin to the following to your `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
bind p run-shell "bash /tmp/search.sh"
```

Make sure you source refresh the configuration in your tmux session and your new binding should initiate the search.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way of doing this is write a bash script to issue the commands back to your tmux.

But I'd like to suggest a mod that allows way more flexible scripting: http://ershov.github.io/tmux/ (I'm the author)

Using this mod, your problem can be solved this way:

```
bind p copy-mode ";" tcl {
  set s [copy-mode-screenline -ex [copy-mode-get-cx]]
  cursor-up
  send-keys "?" "\x15$s"
}
```

This will read the current line from the beginning up to the cursor position and search for the previous occurrence of it.

The key 'p' can be changed to your preference.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I've already got a custom Tmux setup with 24 bit colours that I don't want to break. I ended up using Keyboard Maestro to automatically enter the keystrokes needed. It's hacky, but it works and I'm now able to easily jump to previous prompts.

Maybe if I figure out how to patch Tmux on my own I'll use your mod and the 24 bit mod together. Because being able to script Tmux sounds incredibly useful.